# Trying to create a socket with public IP , java without port forwarding?

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to open a socket with my public IP using Java.

I have a server program and a client program, and I can connect them both using localhost. I also portforwarded my PC on a port, and using this port I can connect the programs.
However, is it possible to connect them without opening ports?

I am developing this IP chat program, and it's quite inconvenient to have all users open their ports.

**Server.java contains:**

```
ServerSocket Server = new ServerSocket(Port number);
```

**Client.java contains:**

```
try {
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket(public_ip, Port number);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am grateful for any assistance, I'm very new to sockets!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inbound connections are blocked by default, this is done due to security reasons. Outbound connections aren't normally blocked. So the best solution is to have a server. Clients will connect to it without problems (outbound connections are allowed), and the server will transfer data to clients.

In case you're curios how the server will be able to deliver messages to the clients using connection, outbound for client - the client keeps asking server if there are new messages, and if so return them in response.

Comment: @OllyScargill not exactly, you keep the messages on the server and let clients connect to the server and fetch them. Don't connect from the server to the clients.